# Datatable and Date Column Manipulation

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, datetime-format

I am working on a database driven c# application.

I have a datatable that has a date column in it. Bind this datatable to datagridview and let the user edit the records and upon clicking save, save these changes in the database.

Date format in grid changes based on the system settings between `dd/MM/yyyy`  and `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Data entry operators are not smart enough to look at this difference, so while editing the records they sometime move the records to different month.

Date Format is `dd/MM/yyyy    10/10/2010`

They want to change it to `12th October` from `10th October`. They made this change `10/12/2010` assuming the date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

There always remains this problem, so I want to fix the date format in the datatable.

What are the approaches I could use?

Comment: Formatting of dates is a UI issue, not a persistence issue. If dates are stored in a `DATETIME` column, that's about it for the database. Fix the UI.

Comment: in the Column properties `DefaultCellStyle` you could set the Format to `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
var style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Format = "dd-MMM-yy";
colDate.DefaultCellStyle = style;
```

You don't need to convert it back and forth, it'll do all the things you want to achieve,

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the Column DataType as DateTime?  I don't understand why this issue can occur.  Internally, .NET should be saving this cell value as DateTime, and passing this to the database.  Date formatting is not an issue.